# For loop to find out if directory exists in unix

Tags: bash, unix, parameters

I want to use a script that checks whether a list of directories exists or not and at the same time it should print some custom message that I am sending.

For example:

I have a script that validates if directory exists or not:

```
**check.sh**

for i in $*
   if [ -d "$i" ]; then
      echo Found <msg-i> directory.
   else
       echo <msg-i> directory not found.
```

Now I want to call this script like this:

```
./check.sh $DIR1 msg1 $Dir2 msg2 $Dir3 msg3
```

So if DIR1 doesn't exist then I want to display message as "msg1 directory not found", similarly for DIR2 I want to show "msg2 directory not found". Here msg1 and msg2 are something I want to pass as string. How to achieve this? I am using bash shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    dir="$1"
    msg="$2"
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        echo "$msg dir FOUND"
    else
        echo "$msg dir NOT FOUND"
    fi
    shift 2
done
```

`shift <n>` command simply shifts left positional parameters passed to the script of n positions.
For example if you call a script with:

`./myscript 1 2 3 4`

`$1` is "1" and `$2` is "2"

but if you `shift 2` then `$1` is "3" and `$2` is "4".

In this way the loop consumes 2 parameters per cycle until `$1` parameter is an empty string ( `-n "$1"`).

`while` condition can be written more elegantly as:

```
while (( $# ))
```

obtaining the same result.

You can also check for the second parameter (`while [ -n "$2" ]`) but this changes the behavior when user provides an odd number of parameters:

- in the first case last directory will be checked but you'll have a strange message because `$msg` il empty
- il the second case you'll not have strange messages, but last directory will silently not be checked

Better test parameters at the beginning:

```
if (( $# % 2 ))
then
    echo "Provide an even number of parameters"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: The `while` condition can simply be `(( $# ))`  (test if the number of positional parameters is non-zero).

Comment: Since you want 2 parameters per loop: `while [[ "$2" ]]`

Comment: Thanks to @chepner: I reported your suggestions in my answer

Comment: Thanks to @glennjackman I reported your suggestion in my answer

Answer (score 4):

Chepner Says:

> The while condition can simply be `(( $# ))` (test if the number of positional parameters is non-zero).

Chaitanya Says:

> Hi Chepner, thanks for providing alternate solution, can you please tell me how the while condition should actually look like in order to use $# , I tried different ways but it is not working for me.

Here's a quick sample:

```
while (( $# ))
do
   dir=$1
   msg=$2
   shift 2
   [...]
done
```

The `while (( $# ))` will be true as long as there are any command line arguments. Doing the `shift` twice removes arguments from the list. When no more arguments, the while loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

@Zac has the correct answer.

One tip for the message: use a `printf` format string:

```
./check.sh dir1 "can't locate %s directory"
```

and in the script:

```
if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]; then
    printf "$msg" "$dir"
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, can you please let me know when can I use `echo` command and when should I use `printf`?

Comment: echo just concatenates its arguments and outputs them. You can use printf if you need finer-grained control over the formatting (e.g. print a number with leading zeros `printf %05d $n`). printf also has a nice feature that it will re-use the format string if there are more arguments than placeholders, so `printf "%s\n" "$@"` is a nice shortcut for `for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done`